# bcrypt 5.1 from npm crashes entire Vue app and breaks node modules when imported into file

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, package.json, bcrypt

I'm trying to add authentication and password hashing to a Vue application. I'm able to install bcrypt with no issues, but when I require it in a file, it causes the entire app to crash. There are multiple errors inside a @mapbox node module folder, and a ton of basic node.js issues. Here is the first error:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

It then has over 50 errors related to 'fs', 'util', 'path' like the one below

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/clean.js 10:15-35

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/se/Documents/dev/lt/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib'

These fs, util, path, module not found errors appear are in a variety of different modules when importing/requiring bcrypt in a file.

Removing bcrypt from the top of my file (no longer requiring or importing it) fixes the issue and everything loads normally again.

I tried reading into webpack and bundlers and installed the latest version of webpack to no avail. I've also read online that it could be babel? so I installed and updated that package but also had no success. I'm scratching my head and I have no idea where to go or what to try at this point.

I'm wondering if there are incompatible packages or maybe I configured something wrong in my package.json so I've listed it here:

```
{
  "name": "learn-together",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js && vue-cli-service serve",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "client": "vue-cli-service serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.14.3",
    "@mapbox/node-pre-gyp": "^1.0.10",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.10.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue3-google-map": "^0.15.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "netlify-cli": "^12.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

If anyone knows what this error could be or what I'm doing wrong would be great, many thanks